# Append '0' to @MONTH if @MONTH has length 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I apologize if this is a really basic question in SQL, but Googling has not helped me explain why this code isn't working.

```
DECLARE @MONTH INT;
SET @MONTH = 3;

DECLARE @MONTH_STR VARCHAR(2);
SET @MONTH_STR = CASE 
                    WHEN NCHAR(@MONTH) = 1 THEN '0' + @MONTH
                    ELSE @MONTH
                 END;
```

This causes an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int.

`@MONTH` can take on values 1, 2, 3, ..., 12 and all `@MONTH_STR` is doing is this: append a `0` to the left of `@MONTH` if the number of characters of `@MONTH` is `1`, otherwise output `@MONTH` as a string of length `2`.

The error message makes no sense to me. I've also tried using `CAST` on `@MONTH` as an `NVARCHAR(2)` variable, but I obtain the same error:

```
DECLARE @MONTH INT;
SET @MONTH = 3;

DECLARE @MONTH_STR VARCHAR(2);
SET @MONTH_STR = CASE
                    WHEN NCHAR(CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2))) = 1
                       THEN '0' + CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2))
                       ELSE CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2))
                 END;
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NCHAR(@MONTH)` is not a conversion/cast - it's a function call that returns the unicode character with the character code 3, so the subsequent comparison is not going to work.

If you want to use a `CASE` then both branches must return a character type:

```
SET @MONTH_STR = case when @MONTH < 10 THEN '0' + CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2))
                 else CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2))
                 end;
```

A simpler way without a case:

```
SET @MONTH_STR = RIGHT('0' + CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second T-SQL block you are trying to get the length of @MONTH, so a LEN is needed.  The below works on my 2008R2 box

```html
DECLARE @MONTH INT;
SET @MONTH = 3;

DECLARE @MONTH_STR VARCHAR(2);
SET @MONTH_STR = case when LEN(CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2))) = 1 THEN '0'+CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2))
                 else CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2))
                 end;

SELECT @MONTH_STR
```